# Where does ASP.NET look for binaries when you compile an ASP.NET 4 web project under x86 (32-bit)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, x86, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 4/Web Api application in VS 2010 on my 64-bit dev machine.  I have IIS installed and am running the project under IIS.  Because I need to interface with a third party component, I have to change the project build configuration to x86 (I'm currently in the Debug build).

In IIS, I configured the application to use an application pool that allows 32-bit processes.  However, when I ran my site, I noticed that code changes I was making were not showing.  It turns out that the assemblies being used were those found in the \bin folder.  After changing the configuration, the compiler's assembly output goes to the \bin\x86\debug folder; it didn't look like IIS was looking there.

I temporarily switched the configuration back to "Any CPU", right-clicked the project node, and selected the **Clean** option.  This removed all the stale assemblies in the \bin folder.  I then switched back to the x86 configuration -- rebuilt the project for good measure -- and tried to run the project again.  Now it wasn't finding any assemblies at all.  I'm getting errors like:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies
```

System.Web.Providers -- and all the rest of the assemblies -- reside in \bin\x86\debug.

- Is IIS supposed to know to look there?
- Is Visual Studio supposed to copy the assemblies up two levels to the \bin folder?

If the latter, that is clearly not happening.  Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if try registering the assembly on GAC?

Comment: It's not just that assembly.  It's ALL assemblies -- even my own which are compiled into the bin\x86\debug folder.  I just did a test and manually copied all the assemblies from bin\x86\debug up two levels to  bin and the site now works.  It seems like I can address this with a post-build step -- but I would think that I shouldn't have to do that and that I've missed some configuration item?

Comment: It definitely sounds strange, and depending where you're hosting this can be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simply to set the Output Path to bin in the Build tab of the project properties. :-)